# updating Stripe Price object

Tags: stripe-payments

I had a question that seems to be easy but apparently is not working.  I need to update the price for a Price object, but the following does not work. It gives the error that **unit_amount** is not known, although we use it to define the Price object initially:

```
stripe.Price.modify(
    "price_1Hkb5FHdAaIdH7ntvOhZOyFK",
    unit_amount=10,
)
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can not modify the price of a `Price` in the API. This is not something that is supported as there's no corresponding parameter on [the API](https://stripe.com/docs/api/prices/update).

If you want to change the amount associated with a `Price`, you would create a new `Price` object and start using it instead. You could also make the old one inactive for example.

Another powerful feature of Stripe's API is the `lookup_key` on `Price` ([doc](https://stripe.com/docs/api/prices/object#price_object-lookup_key)). This lets you define a custom alias for your Price in your code. That way instead of hardcoding the price id `price_123` in your code and having to update it to use `price_abcd`, you can transfer the old lookup key from the old price to the new one and have your code seamlessly start using the new one automatically. The idea is that you either cache the Price id associated with a lookup key based on webhooks for example or use the List Prices API and the `lookup_keys` [parameter](https://stripe.com/docs/api/prices/list#list_prices-lookup_keys) to quickly find the latest price id associated with a given lookup key!

Comment: The name suggests you can pass a list. Is this correct? You wouldn't happen to know the exact format of this parameter would you. Also the docs say _Only return the price with these lookup_keys, if any exist._. Does this mean it only returns a single price object rather than several if an array was used and several keys were passed in?

Comment: If you pass 3 lookup keys it will return up to 3 Prices. And the param is an array of strings so `stripe.Price.list(lookup_keys=['gold','silver','premium'])` for example

Comment: lookup_keys are null in my case, the stripe dashboard also doesn't show an option add a lookup_key, how do I achieve this?

Comment: @reindeer, you can update the lookup_key using the API for updating prices - docs at https://stripe.com/docs/api/prices/update.  I was also wondering why it is not available in the GUI.

Comment: There is a parameter currency_options but it can only be used to add a currency, not to modify. It may be confusing at first.